# Recreating shape using CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, shapes

I'm trying to recreate the shape from the image below with CSS only.

[image]

This is what I've tried:

```html
<svg width="450" height="50">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
          <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#555;stop-opacity:1" />
          <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#333;stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
        <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0">
          <feDropShadow dx="0" dy="4" stdDeviation="3"/>
        </filter>
      </defs>
      <path d="M0,0 L450,0 L450,20 L300,20 C270,20 250,50 230,50 L0,50 Z" fill="url(#grad1)" />
      <path d="M0,0 L450,0 L450,20 L300,20 C270,20 250,50 230,50 L0,50 Z" fill="transparent" filter="url(#f1)" />
  </svg>
```

It is very similar but it is not the same curve I want to achieve and I've used SVG. How to do it with CSS and how to make exactly the same curve?

Here is where I' am stuck with css (I've marked the place for the curve with red color):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

#top-rectangle {
    height: 50px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #555;
}

#bottom-rectangle {
    height: 20px;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #555;
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}

#curve {
    height: 30px;
    width: 2px; 
    background-color: red;
    margin-left: 250px;
}

#curve2 {
    height: 2px;
    width: 30px; 
    background-color: red;
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="top-rectangle"></div>
<div id="bottom-rectangle"></div>
<div id="curve"></div>
<div id="curve2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Consider to use clip-path

Comment: I barely see any CSS in the code you shared, you have to show us what you tried and where you are blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With CSS, curved shapes are typically achieved by using
rounded corners
([border-radius](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius))
or radial gradients
([radial-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient)).
There are various articles on the internet to explain this, for example:
https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-wavy-shapes-patterns-in-css/

An alternative approach is to blend two gradients (one horizontal, one vertical) with extremely high contrast.
The effect is obscure and a bit crude; you may need to play around with the attributes to properly shape the curve.
But it sure is compact. In its most basic form, all you need is this:

```
background-image:
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #3e3e3e, #c1c1c1),
    linear-gradient(to right, black 65%, white 75%);
background-blend-mode: hard-light, normal;
filter: contrast(99);
```

Here's a complete demo:

```css
.tabstrip {
    background-image:
        linear-gradient(to bottom, #3e3e3e, #c1c1c1),
        linear-gradient(to right, black 65%, white 72%);
    background-blend-mode: hard-light, normal;
    mix-blend-mode: lighten;
    filter: contrast(99);
    height: 25px;
}

.demo {
    background: linear-gradient(#555, #333);
    border: thin black solid;
    color: green;
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
}

.above {
    color: white;
    padding: 2px;
}

.under {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 2px;
}

.left {
    color: white;
    left: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.right {
    color: black;
    right: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
<div class="above">Above tabstrip</div>
<div class="left">Left</div>
<div class="right">Right</div>
<div class="tabstrip"></div>
<div class="under">Underneath tabstrip</div>
</div>
```